# Python class function unable to find class variable

Tags: python

I'm new to python, but fairly familiar with OO languages, and I'm struggling with a compilation error that is clear but that I don't understand how to fix.

Here is my class

```
class Neuron(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.__output = 0
        self.__inputNeurons = []

    def initInputNeurons(neuronArray, initialWeight=0):
        for neuron in neuronArray:
            __inputNeurons.append((neuron, initialWeight))

    def activateFromInput(value):
        output = value;

    def activateFromNeurons(activationFunction, threshold=1): 
        sumWeightedInputs = 0
        for connection in __inputNeurons: 
            sumWeightedInputs += connection[0].output * connection[1]
        output = activationFunction(sumWeightedInputs, threshold)
```

Its fairly simple with an init function and a couple options for activation. I initialize the neural network with the following code after reading in my training data .

```
inputNeurons = []
for value in trainingCharacterVecs[0]:
    inputNeurons.append(Neuron())

outputNeurons = []
for value in range(7):
    print(value);
    neuron = Neuron()
    Neuron.initInputNeurons(inputNeurons, value)
    outputNeurons.append(neuron)
```

My error occurs when initializing the outputNeuron array, specifically when running

```
Neuron.initInputNeurons(inputNeurons, value)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./simpleNet.py", line 88, in <module>
Neuron.initInputNeurons(inputNeurons, value)
    File "./simpleNet.py", line 62, in initInputNeurons
__inputNeurons.append((neuron, initialWeight))
NameError: name '_Neuron__inputNeurons' is not defined
```

The error is telling me that **__inputNeurons** does not exist. This is also the case when I define **_inputNeurons** outside the **__init__** function as a static variable.

How should I be defining and accessing class variables in python?

Comment: Note that in Python the term "class method" is distinct from a regular method on a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Python you need to explicitly reference self for each of the references. This means it is your first parameter *AND* it needs to be referenced through dot notation.

Try this:

```
# self is the first parameter
def initInputNeurons(self, neuronArray, initialWeight=0):
    for neuron in neuronArray:
        # direct reference to self
        self.__inputNeurons.append((neuron, initialWeight))

# ... LATER ... 
def activateFromNeurons(self, activationFunction, threshold=1): 
    sumWeightedInputs = 0
    # Note the reference to `self.`
    for connection in self.__inputNeurons: 
        sumWeightedInputs += connection[0].output * connection[1]
    output = activationFunction(sumWeightedInputs, threshold)

# and at the bottom:

    neuron = Neuron()
    # marking this lower case, to match your variable name.
    # otherwise `self` doesn't get passed.
    neuron.initInputNeurons(inputNeurons, value)
    outputNeurons.append(neuron)
```